# How can you predict a combination of categorical and continuous variables with Scikit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with a large number of predictive variables and I want to use them to predict a number of output variables. However, some of the things I want to predict are categorical, and others are continuous; the things I want to predict are *not* independent. Is it possible with scikit-learn to, for example, mix a classifier and a regressor so that I can predict and disentangle these variables? (I'm currently looking at gradient boosting classifiers/regressors, but there may be better options.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use One Hot Encoding or Dummy Variable Encoding, to convert labels to numerics. See the link below for all details.

https://codefires.com/how-convert-categorical-data-numerical-data-python/

As an aside, Random Forest is a popular machine learning model that is commonly used for classification tasks as can be seen in many academic papers, Kaggle competitions, and blog posts. In addition to classification, Random Forests can also be used for regression tasks. A Random Forest’s nonlinear nature can give it a leg up over linear algorithms, making it a great option. However, it is important to know your data and keep in mind that a Random Forest can’t extrapolate. It can only make a prediction that is an average of previously observed labels. In this sense it is very similar to KNN. In other words, in a regression problem, the range of predictions a Random Forest can make is bound by the highest and lowest labels in the training data. This behavior becomes problematic in situations where the training and prediction inputs differ in their range and/or distributions. This is called covariate shift and it is difficult for most models to handle but especially for Random Forest, because it can’t extrapolate.

https://towardsdatascience.com/a-limitation-of-random-forest-regression-db8ed7419e9f

https://stackabuse.com/random-forest-algorithm-with-python-and-scikit-learn

In closing, Scikit-learn uses numpy matrices as inputs to its models. As such all features become de facto numerical (if you have categorical feature you’ll need to convert them to numerical).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a builtin way.  There are `ClassifierChain` and `RegressorChain` that allow you to use earlier predictions as features in later predictions, but as the names indicate they assume either classification or regression.  Two options come to mind:

1. Manually patch those together for what you want to do. For example, use a `ClassifierChain` to predict each of your categorical targets using just the independent features, then add those predictions to the dataset before training a `RegressorChain` with the numeric targets.
2. Use those classes as a base for defining a custom estimator.  In that case you'll probably look mostly at their common parent class `_BaseChain`.  Unfortunately that also uses a single `estimator` attribute, whereas you'd need (at least) two, one classifier and one regressor.